# Python select by attribute using a variable counter

Tags: python, arcpy

I am brand new to python and trying to learn how to do some simple loops but I have hit a snag.  Below is what I am working with, I am trying to select the polygon row by row, but I keep getting EOL errors and various other syntax issues as I try to troubleshoot.  If I remove `""" findMe """` and replace with `""" "pgNum" = 1 """` it works fine.  How can I change 1 to be x?

I am using the python window within ArcGIS

Thanks.

```
import arcpy
workSpc = (r'C:\Users\adams\Downloads\tmp')
smooth = 'MNR_89_Smooth'
grid = 'test_grid'
x = 1

if x == 1:
    findMe = '"pgNum" = ' + str(x)
    print findMe
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("test_grid","NEW_SELECTION",""" findMe """)
    x = x + 1
    print x
```

Comment: what are you trying to do? Loop over something? What are the bounds for x? Is this the whole program?

Comment: I've given an Answer to the specific question but am guessing this may be something a cursor should be used for.

Comment: Agreed. Cursors automatically go through your data row by row and perform each task within the cursor on every row. Here is the help page about cursors: http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002z0000001q000000

Comment: Thanks, I knew I was doing something really wrong, but I have only completed ESRI's first introduction to python.  I will read through the link for a cursor and rewrite.  I was able to solve it by removing the triple quotes and concatenating the field name with the counter.Another dumb question.  How do I add a vote beside PolyGeo's comment?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the triple quotes on both sides of `""" findMe """` in the following line:

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("test_grid","NEW_SELECTION", findMe)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should fix the first bit ***if pgNum is a text field***:

> findMe = ' "pgNum" = ' + " ' " + x + " ' "

(but where I have single and double quotes separated by a space for readability they should abutt)

but @ccn is right that the triple quotes down further in the code need to go too.

Comment: Alternately, `'"pgNum" = {}'.format(x)`